# REMOVER PONTOS E VIRGULAS VB.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net

Amigos, o Mysql não grava corretamente os valores com pontos e virgulas no formato de moeda! eu uso VB.net e  preciso de uma função para remover pontos e virgulas, antes de armazenar o valor no banco de dados!!

exemplo: de 1.200,23 para 120023

Ou seja gostaria de usar a mascara de moeda, e usar uma função para remover os pontos e virgulas antes de armazenar o valor no banco de dados!! espero que alguém compreenda meu problema, e me ajude!

Comment: `Replace`? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Porque você não utiliza o tipo certo, tanto no banco quanto em sua aplicação?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o seguinte para remover os pontos e vírgulas.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dblValor As Double = 10000.58

    MsgBox(dblValor.ToString.Replace(",", "")) 'Tira a vírgula
    MsgBox(dblValor.ToString.Replace(".", "")) 'Tira o ponto
End Sub
```